# Why can't i manually update my access database? (once it is connected to vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

So I have created a project in Vb.net, and have been retrieving, inserting, and updating data from an access database using it. I have realised that I must change some of the records within the database and went about doing so in access (having opened the database within the debug folder). So I would update the records, and then save, before closing it. Whenever I reopened it again, it had reverted to the older version. When trying to overwrite, it corrupted some of the records and sometimes the whole database, saying "Id" is not valid. Is there an error in my logic? Do I have to make a new database connection?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]  Also take care which tags you pick - if it is Access, why the MYSQL tag?

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong. I'm pretty inexperienced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making changes to the wrong database.  The original is, or at least it should be, in the project folder.  When you build, that original is copied to the output folder.  That way, any changes you make while debugging do not pollute the original, so it's clean when it comes time for you to release your application.

Comment: Great, thanks alot! It helps to understand the theory behind it, so that's really helpful!